# Expand rows to contain monthly rows between 2 dates

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have a table 'positions' with the following variable:

```
- id
- role
- startdate
- enddate
```

I need to generate monthly series using data of anothr table. Is there a way to expand each of the rows of the table 'positions' so that each role is expanded into n-rows of months between start date and end date.

For example, Row 1 containing:

```
(0001, 'Salesperson', '2020-01', '2020-05')
```

I need to expand into something like:

```
(0001, 'Salesperson', '2020-01') 
(0001, 'Salesperson', '2020-02') 
(0001, 'Salesperson', '2020-03') 
(0001, 'Salesperson', '2020-04') 
(0001, 'Salesperson', '2020-05')
```

Thanks!

I tried iterating through the table but haven't been able to get the reuslt

Comment: Are you using MySQL or SQL-Server?

Comment: "2020-01" is clearly not a date.   Can we assume this is a string with a yyyy-MM format ?

Comment: Do you have access to a dates reference table? Many existing databases have such pre-populated calendar utility tables that you can use as part of a join query.

Comment: You could use a GROUP BY and GROUP_CONCAT to do this but you will only get 3 colums and the 3rd is a comma delimited set of dates.

Comment: Fix your tags for the appropriate DBMS.

Comment: I am using SQL server. Indeed those are dates in format 'yyyy-mm'.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is tagged with 2 Databases. I am using SQL Server to answer. You can try something like this:

[SQL Fiddle DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9eecb/176353)

```
    DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME = '2018-01-01 00:00:00.000'; -- this can be any date below the minimum StartDate

WITH tt AS (
    SELECT '0001' AS EmployeeID, '2020-01-01 00:00:00.000' AS StartDate, '2020-05-31 00:00:00.000' AS EndDate
  
    ),
MyTable AS 
  (
    SELECT @StartDate AS myDate
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(Month,1,myDate)
    FROM MyTable
    WHERE DATEADD(Month,1,myDate) <=  '2020-05-31 00:00:00.000'
)
SELECT 
    EmpId.EmployeeID,
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(7), a.myDate, 126)
FROM 
    MyTable a
     INNER JOIN 
      (
        SELECT EmployeeID, MIN(StartDate) MinStartDate
        FROM tt
        GROUP BY EmployeeID
      ) EmpId ON 
        a.MyDate >= EmpId.MinStartDate
     LEFT JOIN 
    tt ON
        EmpId.EmployeeID = tt.EmployeeID AND
        a.myDate >= tt.StartDate AND
        a.myDate <= ISNULL(tt.EndDate, GETDATE())
ORDER BY EmpId.EmployeeID DESC, a.MyDate
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

Also I have assumed that your startDate and EndDate are in Date format inside your table.

Comment: Hi thanks for your response. But wouldn't that answer only work for the first row? It is a table with several rows, and I would like to expand each row as I described in the example.